# htaccess prevent access to php files except for style.php files

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

In my main .htaccess file I have this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

To prevert direct access to php files (that are called with seo frendly urls).

now im working on a dynamic CSS code called with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme1/style.php">
```

**there is a way to allow style.php files and block all the others .php files?**

PS: also in my "theme1" directory I have another htaccess with this code:

```
<Files *.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
```

how could I edit these 2 .htaccess files to only allow the style.php file?

Comment: What prevents you from internally rewriting, for example, theme1.css to theme1/style.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to skip that php file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?!.*?style\.php).+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: great! it works, but in my case only without specify the directory

Comment: Glad it worked out. Probably `/theme1/` is not in the requested URL. (edited)